# Python: Tkinter: moving objects from the centre of it with place()

Tags: python, tkinter

I just want to find out how I can move an object/text/... in a window not from the top left corner, but from the centre of itself.

Thanks for helping
PS: English is not my mother language, so I hope my question is understandable.

Comment: Well I could interpret this question differently and that's why the community standard is to provide a [mre]. We all speak the same language in python. In addition it is a sign of good will to put some effort in your own goals before asking others to achieve it. That's the difference between help and work for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try place with relx, rely as a fraction of the height and width of the parent widget.

Example:

```
my_label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello World!")
my_label.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor='center')
```